# Display form for numerical integration (like `\[Esc] dintt \[Esc]`)?

Tags: numerical-integration, display, input-alias

When I use the alias `\[Esc] dintt \[Esc]` to pretty print a definite integral in my notebook, it actually stands for `Integrate[...]`.

I would like to have the same readable format with the integral sign, but to stand for numerical integration, i.e. `NIntegrate[...]`. Is it possible?

Of course, as a workaround wrapping everything in `N` works, like `N[\[Esc] dintt \[Esc]]`.

Comment: `N[\[Esc] dintt \[Esc]]` calls `Integrate` first, so it's not exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) in your alias to control how the alias is interpreted:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] = DeleteDuplicates @ Prepend[
    CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases],
    "ndint" -> TemplateBox[
        {"\[Placeholder]","\[Placeholder]","\[Placeholder]","\[SelectionPlaceholder]"},
        "ndint",
        DisplayFunction -> (
            RowBox[{
                SubsuperscriptBox["\[Integral]", #1, #2], 
                RowBox[{#3, RowBox[{"\[DifferentialD]", #4}]}]
            }]&),
        InterpretationFunction -> (
            RowBox[{
                "NIntegrate", "[",
                RowBox[{#3, ",", RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{#4, ",", #1, ",", #2}], "}"}]}],
                "]"
            }]&
        ),
        Tooltip->"NIntegrate"
    ]
];
```

Here is an animation showing the alias in action:

[image]

One difference with mikado's answer is that only integrals created by the alias are interpreted as a [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) object. Other integrals are interpreted as an [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) object as usual.

Answer (score 2):

The `Notation` package can help you here.  This definition interprets all definite integral expressions as being `NIntegrate` rather than `Integrate`

```
Needs["Notation`"]

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{
SubsuperscriptBox["∫", "u_", "v_"], 
RowBox[{"f_", 
RowBox[{"\[DifferentialD]", "x_"}]}]}]] ⟹ 
  ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"NIntegrate", "[", 
RowBox[{"f_", ",", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"x_", ",", "u_", ",", "v_"}], "}"}]}], "]"}]]]

\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(1\)]\(Sin[
   x] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)
(* 0.459698 *)
```

Unfortunately, this looks a bit of a mess when pasted into the website, but should work when pasted back into Mathematica.